# RCurl form login

Tags: r, post, rcurl

I have read the following questions but cannot quite work this one out. Trying to login to website by posting a form. Please read below:

Working example:

Loading packages:

```
install.packages("RHTMLForms", repos = "http://www.omegahat.org/R", type = "source") require(RHTMLForms) 
require(RCurl) 
require(XML)
```

I am connecting to https://www.moodys.com/:

```
 url <- getURL("https://www.moodys.com/", 
               cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL",
               "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl"))
```

Getting the login form:

```
forms <- getHTMLFormDescription(url)
```

and post the form back:

```
fun <- createFunction(forms$aspnetForm)
results <- fun(MdcUserName = "xxx@xxx", MdcPassword="xxxx")
```

which gives me the following error message:

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  Could not resolve host: NA; Host not found
```

I understand that replicating/solving this error might require a valid username and password, but it is much appreciated.

Similar questions:

[R - posting a login form using RCurl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19074359/r-posting-a-login-form-using-rcurl)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327001/https-php-login-via-rcurl-post

[What if I want to web scrape with R for a page with parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601520/what-if-i-want-to-web-scrape-with-r-for-a-page-with-parameters)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Selenium` and [RSelenium](https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium) to login to the webpage

```
library(RSelenium)
RSelenium::startServer()
appURL <- "http://www.moodys.com"
username <- "someuser"
password <- "somepass"
remDr <- remoteDriver()
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate(appURL)
logIn <- remDr$findElement("id", "LoginText")
logIn$clickElement()
userName <- remDr$findElement("id", "MdcUserName")
userName$sendKeysToElement(list(username))
passWord <- remDr$findElement("id", "MdcPassword")
passWord$sendKeysToElement(list(password))
logIn <- remDr$findElement("id", "LoginImageButton")
logIn$clickElement()
```

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to RSelenium; will be good to get to grips with. I feel the root cause of my issue might be a connection error. Running your suggested code, I get stuck on                                  > remDr$open()
[1] "Connecting to remote server"
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : couldn't connect to host                                                                     Do you know how to resolve this? SO suggests looking at options(RCurlOptions = list(proxy = "xxx", proxyport = xx)) but I don't know how to proceed. Thanks in advance

Comment: Is a server started `RSelenium::startServer()`. To download a server run `RSelenium::checkForServer()`. The link in the answer has a number of vignettes which will help also. `remDr <- remoteDriver()` assumes firefox is installed.